# A function differentiable at a point but not continuous

Tags: calculus

Is $\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ differentiable at $x=0$? ($\mathrm{sgn}$ is sign function).

For $x>0$, $f'(x)=0$. For $x<0$, $f'(x)=0$. At $x=0$, $f(x)=0$ and $f'(x)=0$.

But the function is discontinuous at $x=0$.

Comment: It's not differentiable at $0$. Trying to calculate gives $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{sgn (h) }{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{|h|}$, which does not converge to a finite value.

Answer (score 3):

No. Differentiability is a stronger condition than continuity. In particular, $f$ differentiable at $x$ implies $f$ continuous at $x$.

Said differently, $f$ discontinuous at $x$ implies $f$ not differentiable at $x$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean

$$\operatorname {sgn}(x)=\begin{cases}1, & x>0\\0, &x=0\\-1, & x<0\end{cases}$$

Clearly, for $x\neq 0$, $\operatorname {sgn}'(x)=0$. Let's see what happens at $0$.

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac {\operatorname {sgn}(x)-\operatorname {sgn}(0)}{x-0}=\lim \frac 1 x\to \infty$$

Thus $\operatorname {sgn}(x)$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

To add to MPW's answer, look at the definition of the derivative: $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(h)-\operatorname{sgn}(0)}{h}.$$ However we define $\operatorname{sgn}(0)$, this limit will not exist.